# improve database table design depending on a value of a type in a column

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have the following:
1. A table **"patients"** where I store patients data.
2. A table **"tests"** where I store data of tests done to each patient.

Now the problem comes as I have 2 types of tests **"tests_1"** and **"tests_2"**
So for each test done to particular patient I store the type and id of the type of test:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS patients
(
    id_patient   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name_patient VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    sex_patient VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    date_patient DATE
);

INSERT INTO patients values 
(1,'Joe',  'Male'  ,'2000-01-23');
INSERT INTO patients values 
(2,'Marge','Female','1950-11-25');
INSERT INTO patients values 
(3,'Diana','Female','1985-08-13');
INSERT INTO patients values 
(4,'Laura','Female','1984-12-29');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tests
(
    id_test         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    id_patient      INTEGER,
    type_test       VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    id_type_test    INTEGER,
    date_test   DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_patient) REFERENCES patients(id_patient)
);
INSERT INTO tests values
(1,4,'test_1',10,'2004-05-29');
INSERT INTO tests values
(2,4,'test_2',45,'2005-01-29');
INSERT INTO tests values
(3,4,'test_2',55,'2006-04-12');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tests_1
(
    id_test_1  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    id_patient INTEGER,
    data1         REAL,
    data2         REAL,
    data3         REAL,
    data4         REAL,
    data5         REAL,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_patient) REFERENCES patients(id_patient)
);
INSERT INTO tests_1 values
(10,4,100.7,1.8,10.89,20.04,5.29);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tests_2
(
    id_test_2   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    id_patient INTEGER,
    data1         REAL,
    data2         REAL,
    data3         REAL,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_patient) REFERENCES patients(id_patient)

);
INSERT INTO tests_2 values
(45,4,10.07,18.9,1.8);
INSERT INTO tests_2 values
(55,4,17.6,1.8,18.89);
```

Now I think this approach is redundant or not to good...

So I would like to improve queries like

```
select * from tests WHERE id_patient=4;
select * from tests_1 WHERE id_patient=4;
select * from tests_2 WHERE id_patient=4;
```

Is there a better approach?

In this example I have 1 test of type **tests_1** and 2 tests of type **tests_2** for patient with **id=4**.

[Here is a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/182e8/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the requirement

For OLTP I would do something like the following

STAFF:

```
ID | FORENAME | SURNAME | DATE_OF_BIRTH | JOB_TITLE   | ... 
-------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | harry    | potter  | 2001-01-01    | consultant  | ...
 2 | ron      | weasley | 2001-02-01    | pathologist | ...
```

PATIENT:

```
ID | FORENAME | SURNAME | DATE_OF_BIRTH | ...
-----------------------------------------------
 1 | hermiony | granger | 2013-01-01    | ...
```

TEST_TYPE:

```
 ID | CATEGORY    | NAME | DESCRIPTION           | ...
--------------------------------------------------------
  1 | haematology | abg  | arterial blood gasses | ...
```

REQUEST:

```
ID | TEST_TYPE_ID | PATIENT_ID | DATE_REQUESTED | REQUESTED_BY | ...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | 1            | 1          | 2013-01-02     | 1            | ...
```

RESULT_TYPE:

```
ID | TEST_TYPE_ID | NAME | UNIT | ...
---------------------------------------
 1 | 1            | co2  | kPa  | ...
 2 | 1            | o2   | kPa  | ...
```

RESULT:

```
ID | REQUEST_ID | RESULT_TYPE_ID | DATE_RESULTED | RESULTED_BY | RESULT | ...
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | 1          | 1              | 2013-01-02    | 2           | 5      | ...
 2 | 1          | 2              | 2013-01-02    | 2           | 5      | ...
```

A concern I have with the above is with the `unit` of the test result, these can sometimes (not often) change. It may be better to place the `unit` un the result table.

Also consider breaking these into the major test categories as my understanding is they can be quite different e.g. histopathology and xrays are not resulted in the similar ways as haematology and microbiology are.

For OLAP I would combine request and result into one table adding derived columns such as `REQUEST_TO_RESULT_MINS` and make a single dimension from `RESULT_TYPE` and `TEST_TYPE` etc.

Answer (score 3):

Add a table `testtype (id_test,name_test)` and use it an FK to the `id_type_test` field in the `tests` table. Do not create seperate tables for `test_1` and `test_2`

Comment: Also, drop the column type_test from tests.

Comment: How would a query using that table look like using testtype ? I would have to join those tables ?

Comment: Yes you would have to join those tables, but the `testtype` table will be very small, will have an index on the PK and will have minimal impact on your query performance. (You should also be indexing the FK field in the `tests` table.

Comment: You said "Do not create tables for test_1 and test2" I have done this fiddle but Still do not get it how to add values depending on type of test `INSERT INTO tests_1 values
(10,4,100.7,1.8,10.89,20.04,5.29);
INSERT INTO tests_2 values
(45,4,10.07,18.9,1.8);
INSERT INTO tests_2 values
(55,4,17.6,1.8,18.89);`  here is the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/a2925

Comment: In your fiddle, you are inserting the values 10,45,55 in the `id_type_test` column, these are not valid test type ids. Test types can only be 1 or 2. I think you need a `test_result` column in the `tests`table to hold the actual value of the test result.

Comment: Ok, I get it but in the case of test_1 I need to hold 5 values, and for test_2 I need to hold 3 values, so this `resul_table` will have its id, and 5 columns, depending on which test is, i would fill 3 or the 5 fields, Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you would need a results table it there are more than 1 result per test. Sorry, I didn't get that from the original post.

Comment: so it would look like: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS results 
(
   id_result INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   val1      REAL,
  val2      REAL,
  val3      REAL,
  val4      REAL,
  val5      REAL,
  
);`  anf if it is test_1 type I would fill all fields, in the case of test_2 type, I would fill only three fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a few ways. without knowing all the different type of cases you need to deal with.

The simplest would be 5 tables

- Patients (like you described it)
- Tests (like you described it)
- TestType (like Declan_K suggested)
- TestResultCode
- TestResults

TestRsultCode describe each value that is stored for each test. TestResults is a pivoted table that can store any number of test-results per test,:

```
Create table TestResultCode
(
  idTestResultCode int
, Code varchar(10)
, Description varchar(200)
, DataType int -- 1= Real, 2 = Varchar, 3 = int, etc.
);

Create Table TestResults
(
  idPatent int -- FK
, idTest   int -- FK
, idTestType int -- FK
, idTestResultCode int -- FK
, ResultsI real
, ResultsV varchar(100)
, Resultsb int
, Created datetime
)
```

so, basically you can fit the results you wanted to add into the tables "tests_1" and "tests_2" and any other tests you can think of.

The application reading this table, can load each test and all its values. Of course the application needs to know how to deal with each case, but you can store any type of test in this structure.

---